# Unity - one Dropdown callback for multiple Dropdown components

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, dropdown

I have a UI with a number of dropdown controls, each affecting one of an array or items. I use onValueChanged(int index), each hooked up to its own listener (selected01(), selected02() ... etc).

This is a bit messy. It would be much better to have one callback - selected(Dropdown instance, int index) - which handles all of them. The callback would identify the control from the instance parameter and act on the appropriate array item.

I cannot see how to do that - onValueChanged() only provides an index not the source. Yet I am sure I have seen a solution to this, possibly involving a Delegate, but cannot now find it.

Any suggestions? (The same could apply to any array of controls, not just Dropdowns).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I could see [`onValueChanged`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.3/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.Dropdown-onValueChanged.html) anyway returns the instance of `DropDown` that was changed.

---

Maybe that is different in the version you are using.

You can simply create your own listener method and do e.g.

```
public DropDown[] dropdowns;

private void HandleChange(DropDown dropdown, int newIndex)
{
    // Your stuff here
}

...

foreach(var dropdown in dropdowns)
{
    var currentDropdown = dropdown;
    currentDropdown.onValueChanged.AddListener((newIndex) => { HandleChange(currentDropdown, newIndex); });
}
```

Comment: Ah, useful. Where did you find that? From what I could see onValueChanged() only passed the index as a parameter, not the instance and the index? (I was just looking at what the inspector showed as being passed back). I'm using (nearly) the latest version on the Unity tools, 2019.3.14F1.

Comment: Ah no, I've got it. Not familiar with lambda expressions (I come from C++land), but it appears the lambda expression effectively creates an anonymous function for each element in the Dropdown array, and in that then calls the generic handler with an extra parameter, being the Dropdown instance. Is that right?

Comment: @nmw01223 yes exactly. The lambda expression basically "knows" the given parameter type (in this case `(int newIndex)`) and the part after the `=>` is basically the anonymous function to be called with that parameter. Within there you can - as done here - simply call your target method with additional parameters - in this case the `currentDropdown` reference

Comment: Thanks. Marked this as the snswer. Slightly uneasy about the compiler inferring the data types, but it seems to work. Created myself a utility class with some standard methods for doing this, and they work fine. I suppose the key point is that the individual functions per callback array item are still needed, but this way the compiler creates them automatically as opposed to me doing it manually - tedious and errorprone.